# vs code ui editor for json schemas

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, jsonschema

Hei Guys,
I wonder if it is possible to edit jsons according to json schemas like `settings.json` in a ui form in vs code?

Can anyone tell if this is possible in vs code?

Answer (score -1):

Yep!  Although support for `$schema` in instance data isn't something that JSON Schema defines, it has become something of a convention.

VSCode supports declaring `$schema` in your data, and even supports relative paths.

[image]

In this example, my JSON data file `Untitled-1.json` is defined in the same folder as `schema.json`.

Comment: this is not what I was expecting even if it might be right. Maybe I should have asked different: is there something similar to this https://github.com/json-editor as a vs code extension?

Comment: Oh, you want an HTML form generated from the schema.  Not sure on specifics, but if you check out https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#web-ui-generation you might find what you need.  I don't see anything for VS Code specifically, but the libraries listed there may lead you to something.  We'd be interested in what you find, so post back if you find something.